# SystemStackError (Stack level too deep) when using wicked_pdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am getting the error `SystemStackError in StaticPagesController#index
stack level too deep` when I try to access to any page within my site just after adding the gem **'wicked_pdf', github: 'mileszs/wicked_pdf'** and running bundle.

I created a new app on rails to test the same gem and I didn't get any error, however when I used the gem on a different developed project I had the same error, I also ran the main project in different computers with different OS. I do not know what could it be.

Logs:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 144ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)



SystemStackError (stack level too deep):

remotipart (1.4.2) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:16:in `render_with_remotipart'
/Users/user/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/wicked_pdf-f4941b7f64ec/lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:46:in `call'
/Users/user/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/wicked_pdf-f4941b7f64ec/lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:46:in `render_with_wicked_pdf'
/Users/user/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/wicked_pdf-f4941b7f64ec/lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:30:in `render'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After a quick google, I suspect [the top reported issue in the `wicked_pdf` project](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/810) duplicates your report. Judging the the comments there, you may find it best to downgrade to `1.1.0` until the issue is fixed.

Comment: Thanks man for taking the time to look over this problem, I'll try an earlier version.

Comment: Yeah, it worked! Thanks @TomLord

Comment: @user2382683 Please try version `1.2.2`, which should fix this issue, and let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was due to a [bug](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/810) in the latest version (1.2.0 at that time) of wicked_pdf as [Tom Lord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954610/tom-lord) pointed out in the comments.